# PDO Connection Error Within Recursive PHP Function

Tags: php, function, recursion, pdo

I've written the following function that pulls a handful of items at random from a store. The final array of items will be roughly within $50 of a value the user puts in (in this case $300).

```
<? 
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../../pdocon.inc.php'; 
$pdo->exec("USE database_waww");

$userValue = 300;
$resultArray = array();

function pullItem($spaceleft,&$resultArray){
    global $pdo;

    if ($spaceleft > 50) {
        $getItem=$pdo->query("SELECT id,price FROM items WHERE price < $spaceleft ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
        $itemFound = $getItem->rowCount();

        if ($itemFound == 1) {
            $results = $getItem->fetchAll();
            foreach ($results as $row){
                $spaceleft = $spaceleft-$row["price"];
                $resultArray[]=$row["id"];
                pullItem($spaceleft,$resultArray);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $spaceleft = 0;
        pullItem($spaceleft,$resultArray);}
    }
    return $resultArray;
}

$findAllItems = pullItem($userValue,$resultArray);
print_r($findAllItems);
?>
```

I'm having trouble with the PDO connection in the recursive function. After running the function a handful of times, it returns the following:

```
PHP Warning:  PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1461 Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382)
```

I believe this is because the pdo connections multiply during the recursion, but I'm not sure. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try using `$getItem->closeCursor()` before each recursive call to `pullItem`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php#refsect1-pdostatement.closecursor-examples) or else you will have a multitude of unfetched rows from the prepared results. If you still need to fetch items from `$getItem`, you should instead populate them into an array using `fetchAll` rather than burdening PDO with a multitude of unfetched results. You should be aware of memory limits at that point, however.

```
function pullItem($spaceleft,&$resultArray){
    global $pdo;

    if ($spaceleft > 50) {
        $getItem=$pdo->query("SELECT id,price FROM items WHERE price < $spaceleft ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
        $itemFound = $getItem->rowCount();

        if ($itemFound == 1) {
            $results = $getItem->fetchAll();
            $getItem->closeCursor();
            unset($getItem);
            foreach ($results as $row) {
                $spaceleft = $spaceleft-$row["price"];
                $resultArray[]=$row["id"];
                pullItem($spaceleft,$resultArray);
        } else { // In case ($itemFound == 1) isn't satisfied
            $getItem->closeCursor();
            unset($getItem);
        }
    }
    else {
        $spaceleft = 0;
        pullItem($spaceleft,$resultArray);}
    }
    return $resultArray;
}
```

[You should also be safely binding your user-input values to the queries to prevent SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) and fully utilize the PDO library

Comment: Good point on using fetchAll to lighten the load. However, after applying the closeCursor(), I still get the same error after a few runs of the function.

Comment: @dsol828 Try my edit, I've combined Sachin's answer as well for good measure, but I noticed you could still get a PDO leak if `$itemFound != 1`, which is an extremely likely scenario. Also removed references where `$getItem` isn't actually declared (`$spaceleft >= 50`)

Comment: @dsol828 For example, `$itemFound` could be `0` but could also be `2` or greater to an unknown magnitude depending on the query and its pertinent results.

Comment: The mix of the two methods appears to be holding. As for the $itemFound issue, I do in fact have an "else" statement in my code, just cut it here to shorten the code. And I don't believe $itemFound could =2 since the query has a LIMIT 1. And of course will protect against injection on the $userValue. Thanks for the comprehensive look, though!

Answer (score 0):

Destroy some old statement object .Try unsetting `$getItem`

here :

```
if ($spaceleft > 50) {
 unset($getItem);
 // ... Further code
```

Comment: Even after applying the unset() ... I still get the same error after running the function several times.